# How do I use ng-grid with Angular HotTowel

Tags: angularjs, breeze, ng-grid, hottowel

I am using John Papa's Angular HotTowel and I don't know how to incorporate Angulars ng-grid into the html. Here is what I've added thanks to wonderful help from stondo.  Breeze seems to be adding extra information that is no allowing ng-grid to render the data in the grid. Is there a way to strip the extra info that breeze sends or a work around for ng-grid to behave correctly with breeze data?

```
 angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    ['common', 'datacontext','$scope', '$http', grid2]);

function grid2(common, datacontext, $scope, $http) {
 .....
 .....
 } else {
      $http.get('/breeze/Breeze/NoBadgePersonnels').success(function (largeLoad) {
                    $scope.setPagingData(largeLoad, page, pageSize);
                });
activate();

function activate() {
     common.activateController([mockData()], controllerId)
         .then(function() { log('Activated Grid View'); });

function mockData() {
     return datacontext.getEmployeePartialsNoBadges().then(function (data) {
          return vm.grid2 = data.results;
     });
   }
 }
```

Additional information

Datacontext.js looks as follows:
    (function () {
    'use strict';

```
var serviceId = 'datacontext';
angular.module('app').factory(serviceId,
    ['common', 'config', 'entityManagerFactory', datacontext]);

function datacontext(common, config, emFactory ) {
    var EntityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery;
    var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
    var log = getLogFn(serviceId);
    var logError = getLogFn(serviceId, 'error');
    var logSuccess = getLogFn(serviceId, 'success');
    var manager = emFactory.newManager();
    var $q = common.$q;

    var service = {
        getPeople: getPeople,
        getMessageCount: getMessageCount,
        getEmployeePartials: getEmployeePartials,    
        getEmployeePartialsNoBadges: getEmployeePartialsNoBadges  
    };

    var entityNames = {
        personnel: 'Personnel'
    };
    return service;

    function getEmployeePartialsNoBadges() {
        var orderBy = 'lname';
        var employees;  //variable to hold employees once we get them back

        //use query using Employees resource
        return EntityQuery.from('NoBadgePersonnels')
            .select('id, fname, lname, class, zip, cntySnrDte')
            .orderBy(orderBy)
                .toType('Personnel')
                .using(manager).execute()
                .then(querySucceeded, _queryFailed)

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            employees = data.results;
            log('Retrieved [Employee Partials] from remote data source', employees.length, true);
            //log('Retrieved [Employee Partials] from remote data source');
            return employees;
        }
    }


    function _queryFailed(error) {
        var msg = config.appErrorPrefix + 'Error retrieving data from entityquery' + error.message;
        logError(msg, error);
        throw error;
    }
```

=================================
It seems like the grid sees 5 items that I queried for, however the items don't want to display on the cells.  Red arrow indicates that it allocated 5 rows, and green arrow indicates that I have selected one of the rows.  Still doesn't display the records.

[image: something is creating rows in the grid, but not displaying info]

thanks
nick

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify John Papa's Hottowel.Angular template, because it wasn't working as expected with latest angular/breeze versions. I'll later share a github link and a blog post about that.

I was able to get ng-grid working just adding $scope and $http to the controller. Read the comment inside the code block to see how it could be entirely done without inject $http.

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var controllerId = 'corrieri';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common', 'datacontext', '$scope', '$http', corrieri]); //'$http', '$scope',

function corrieri(common, datacontext, $scope, $http) { //,$http, $scope
    var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
    var log = getLogFn(controllerId);

    var vm = this;

    $scope.corrieriList = [];

    vm.corrieri = [];


    vm.news = {
        title: 'Corrieri',
        description: 'Lista Corrieri'
    };
    vm.title = 'Corrieri';


    //ng-grid test
    $scope.filterOptions = {
        filterText: "",
        useExternalFilter: false
    };
    $scope.totalServerItems = 0;
    $scope.pagingOptions = {
        pageSizes: [10, 20, 30],
        pageSize: 10,
        currentPage: 1
    };
    $scope.setPagingData = function (data, page, pageSize) {
        data = data.map(function (item) {
            return {
                PK_ID: item.PK_ID,
                Ragione_Sociale: item.Ragione_Sociale,
                Telefono: item.Telefono,
                Nazionalita: item.Nazionalita,
                Indirizzo: item.Indirizzo,
                Cap: item.Cap,
                Provincia: item.Provincia,
                Descrizione: item.Descrizione
            };
        });
        var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
        $scope.corrieriList = pagedData; //.results;
        $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;            
        if (!$scope.$$phase) {
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    };
    $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var data;
            if (searchText) {
                var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
                $http.get('breeze/Corrieri/GetCorrieri').success(function (largeLoad) {
                    var myModArray = largeLoad.map(function (item) {
                        return {
                            Pk_ID: item.Pk_ID,
                            Ragione_Sociale: item.Ragione_Sociale,
                            Telefono: item.Telefono,
                            Nazionalita: item.Nazionalita,
                            Indirizzo: item.Indirizzo,
                            Cap: item.Cap,
                            Provincia: item.Provincia,
                            Descrizione: item.Descrizione
                        };
                    });
                    data = myModArray.filter(function (item) {
                        return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                    });
                    $scope.setPagingData(data, page, pageSize);
                });
            } else {
                $http.get('breeze/Corrieri/GetCorrieri').success(function (largeLoad) {
                    $scope.setPagingData(largeLoad, page, pageSize);
                });
            }
        }, 100);
    };

    $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);

    $scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
            $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
        }
    }, true);
    $scope.$watch('filterOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
        }
    }, true);

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'corrieriList', 
        enablePaging: true,
        showFooter: true,
        showFilter: true,
        enableCellEdit: true,
        enableColumnResize: true,
        enableColumnReordering: true,
        pinSelectionCheckbox: true,
        totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions
    };       
    //ng-grid test end



    activate();

    function activate() {
        var promises = [getCorrieri()];
        common.activateController(promises, controllerId)
            .then(function () {
                log('Activated Corrieri View');
        });

    }


    //This function was used to get data using Breeze Controller
    //and I was even able to use it to bind data to ng-grid
    //calling the function getCorrieri inside my controller and binding
    //gridOptions data to vm.corrieri or just the name of the function (in my case getCorrieri)
    // $scope.gridOptions = { data: getCorrieri}
    //Be aware that since we r using a Breeze Controller data retrieved have additional
    //informations, so we have to remove those, if we bind using vm.corrieri.
    //I found it easier to implement paging using $http and $scope, even though I think
    //I could do it using only $scope and breeze.
    //getCorrieri().then(function() {
    //    angular.forEach(vm.corrieri, function (cor) {
    //        delete cor._backingStore['$id'];
    //        delete cor._backingStore['$type'];
    //        $scope.corrieriList.push(cor._backingStore);
    //    });
    //});
    function getCorrieri() {
        return datacontext.getCorrieri().then(function (data) {
            return vm.corrieri = data.results;
        });
    }

}
})();
```

Below you can find my html for reference. Make sure to surround your's ng-grid div with data-ng-controller or just ng-controller='corrieri'

```
<section id="corrieri-view" class="mainbar" data-ng-controller="corrieri as vm">
    <section class="matter">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">               
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="widget wgreen">
                        <div data-cc-widget-header title="Corrieri" allow-collapse="true"></div>
                            <div class="widget-content text-center text-info">
                                <div data-ng-controller='corrieri'>
                                   <div class="gridStyle col-md-12" ng-grid="gridOptions">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget-foot">
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

Btw, don't forget to add 'ngGrid' to your modules list in app.js

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ngGrid', other modules])
```

and also include ng-grid css and js in index.html (that is obvious, but better safe than sorry)

I struggled a few days to get this working properly, so I hope to help anyone out there having the same problem.

Comment: Hi stondo, thanks for helping out, I've been going nutty for 6 weeks.  I edited the code and added  $http.get('breeze/grid2/getEmployeePartialsNoBadges').  It seems like data is retrieved, but it still doesn't go into the grid.  I'm getting a 404.  I attached an image on my original post above under "Additional Information" of the message I'm getting.  Can you see anything obvious. Again thanks.  Nick

Comment: Hi Nick, 404 means NOT FOUND, so the endpoint is not correct. Since u're using Chrome, install Postman a REST client or Fiddler and test your URL/route with those. Also, are u using Breeze that comes with hottowel.angular template? Are u using a BreezeController (C# side) as well? Using $http doesn't require a BreezeController. Breeze adds information to data transfered that can cause problems. Any way, one step at a time. U could also try with a standard API controller and without Breeze. But if u absolutely want to use breeze I'll create a github project with my working solution

Comment: Thanks stondo for the tip, Fiddler helped me find the the path to /breeze/Breeze/NoBadgePersonnels. I plugged in the path but it didn't show records in grid again.  This is what fiddler showed and you were right, it has extra info.

Comment: [{"$id":"1","$type":"_IB_t6VeV63J0EWyVTqhZWPtZmzfUxU[[System.Int32, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib]], mscorlib]], _IB_t6VeV63J0EWyVTqhZWPtZmzfUxU_IdeaBlade","Id":5492,"Fname":"REBECCA ","Lname":"AGARR ","Class":"HEALTH ","Zip":"99904 ","CntySnrDte":"1900-01-01T00:00:00.000"},

Comment: sorry had to break these comments into 3 section, keep running into character limits. It seems like something with $type and other stuff is in the data.  I am using Breeze that is shown in John Papa angular spa course template and side waffle AngularJs Controller using 'Controller as'. Is side waffle I'm using a BreezeController? It seems like I am using breeze in the datacontext.js.  I'm unsure how to use standard API controller and was just following along with the course.  Would standard API change the way I access data in datacontext.js.  I would like to see breeze sample, if you have.

Comment: Seems like the grid is allocating 5 rows for the 5 records I queried for, however the records don't still display in the cells.

Comment: I've updated the screen shot above to show what he grid looks like.  Still no rendering of the data

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common', 'datacontext', '$scope', grid]);

    function grid(common, datacontext, $scope) {
      $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'vm.employees'
      };

      activate();

      function activate() {
        common.activateController([getEmployees()], controllerId)
              .then(function () { log('Activated Grid View'); });
      }

      //get data for employees
      function getEmployees() {
        return datacontext.getEmployeePartialsNoBadges().then(function (mydata) {
          return vm.employees = data;
        });
      }
    }
```

here is an image of what I see[image]
and here is the code I changed:

```
        function getEmployees() {
            return datacontext.getEmployeePartialsNoBadges().then(function (mydata) {
                log(JSON.stringify(mydata));
                    return vm.employees = mydata.data;
            });
```

Here is some additional info showing the data is coming through.  Remote data source shows 1496 records.  The preview for /breeze/breeze show data.  I've blanked out sensitive info.
[image]

Here is the getEmployeePartialsNoBadges() method in my datacontext that was using entity framework:

```
        function getEmployeePartialsNoBadges() {
        var orderBy = 'lname';
        var employees;  //variable to hold employees once we get them back

        //use query using Employees resource
        return EntityQuery.from('NoBadgePersonnels')
            .select('id, fname, lname, class, zip, cntySnrDte')
            .orderBy(orderBy)
                .toType('Personnel')
                .using(manager).execute()
                .then(querySucceeded, _queryFailed)

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            employees = data.results;         //fillup the variable for employee with results
            log('Retrieved [Employee Partials] from remote data source', employees.length, true);
            //log('Retrieved [Employee Partials] from remote data source');
            return employees;
        }
    }
```

==============================  Nick ==============================

This is what my new mockup looks like now and I put this in datacontext calling it getPeople:

```
       function getPeople() {

        var people = [
            { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Papa', age: 25, location: 'Florida' },
            { firstName: 'Ward', lastName: 'Bell', age: 31, location: 'California' },
            { firstName: 'Colleen', lastName: 'Jones', age: 21, location: 'New York' },
            { firstName: 'Madelyn', lastName: 'Green', age: 18, location: 'North Dakota' },
            { firstName: 'Ella', lastName: 'Jobs', age: 18, location: 'South Dakota' },
            { firstName: 'Landon', lastName: 'Gates', age: 11, location: 'South Carolina' },
            { firstName: 'Haley', lastName: 'Guthrie', age: 35, location: 'Wyoming' }
        ];
        return $q.when(people);
    }
```

I have reworked html and controller code to clean things up. The html is now call grid2.html and the controller is called grid2.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var controllerId = 'grid2';

 angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    ['common', 'datacontext','$scope', grid2]);

function grid2(common, datacontext, $scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.grid2 = [];
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'vm.grid2'
    };

    var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
    var log = getLogFn(controllerId);
    vm.activate = activate;
    vm.title = 'Grid2';

     activate();

    function activate() {
        common.activateController([mockData()], controllerId)
            .then(function() { log('Activated Grid View'); });

        function mockData() {
             return datacontext.getPeople().then(function (mydata) {
                log(JSON.stringify(mydata));
                return vm.grid2 = mydata.data;
            });
        }
    }
}
})();
```

controller grid2.js

```
<section class="mainbar" data-ng-controller="grid2 as vm">
<section class="matter">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="widget wgreen">
               <div data-cc-widget-header title="Grid 2"></div>
                <div class="widget-content user">
                </div>
                this is grid2 test
                <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>

                <div class="widget-foot">
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here what the screen looks like now.  still no data in the grid:

[image: grid view]

In the debug, the data property shows undefined still

[image: mydata.data undefined]

The mydata does contain array of data

[image: mydata containing data]

The vm is an empty array on the return statement

[image: vm empty array on return]

The vm.grid becomes empty after the return and I'm unsure what the vm is also

[image: after return]

The console show data being present

[image]

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  The grid still stays empty. The grid.html does have:  <div class="gridStyle" data-ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>

Comment: Is gridEmployeePartialsNoBadges() returning from a server query? If so you will need to set vm.employees = mydata.data in the getEmployees functions then method.

Comment: Yes, the data is coming from sql server.  I added (edited) the latest code above as you explained, that didn't work either. It almost seems like the html is not seeing ng-scope, but unsure how to test that.

Comment: If you are using Chrome, click F12 to open the developer tools and tab to the console. you should watch the browser console for errors. Also do a log(JSON.stringify(mydata)) to see if you have any data returned from the server. Add this line before the "return vm.employees = mydata.data;". Please post what you see in your console.

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework in your remote data source and returning these out? It appears "TypeError:Converting circular structure to JSON" seems to be the issue. If so, I would use a Data Transfer Object to send out rather than the entity themselves. It also appears there is reference to the same object internally in the structure that is being returned. I would for the time being mock the data in the remote call and see if the grid works.

Comment: Mock the data in the datacontext.getEmployeePartialsNoBadges() method for the time being to see if the grid works.

Comment: I do use entity framework and breeze. I have attached code above showing how getEmployeePartialsNoBadges() was being coded up in datacontext previously.  Now I have added a mockup called getPeople().  When I run this, the log(JSON) shows the data, but it still doesn't reflect in the grid. Thanks.  Nick

Comment: Can you add the following code to your grid controller:
         function grid(common, datacontext, $scope) {
           vm.employees = [];
           $scope.gridOptions = {
             data: 'vm.employees'
           };

Comment: Hi gopiTK, I reworked the html and controller calling them both grid2. Above I have posted the code for both and modified your suggestions, except it is now called vm.grid2.  Things till didn't show up in the ng-grid.  I am also showing the values in debug that I found.  It seems like the array[0] exist for grid and then the grid array disappears and grid is undefined after return statement. thanks Nick.